# Unable to JAR on Mac using Eclipse or VS Code

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, jar, executable-jar

I am a student and I am trying to JAR a java project using a GUI. The project works in eclipse, however when I try and jar the code my macbook cannot gives me this error:

> Java Application launch Failed

I have verified that I am on Java 8 and have tried running the JAR from command-line to no avail. I have also tried to JAR many projects on this computer however it only works once I transfer the files to a Windows computer. I have also tried to jar projects from VS Code which doesn't work.

input: `java -jar VisualBinarySearchTree.jar output`

(this is the jar I want to access)

Error:

> Unable to access jarfile VisualBinarySearchTree.jar

My Java version is 1.8

The JAR also doesn't work if I just double click on it and the jar is being created through eclipse by `export>RunnableJarFile>extract` libraries.

Comment: What exactly are you typing in the command line, and what exactly is the response? Note that the current version of Java is Java 21.

Comment: input : java -jar <jarName>.jar output Error: Unable to access jarfile VisualBinarySearchTree.jar also my java version is java version 1.8

Comment: Well is VisualBinarySearchTree the name of the jar you are trying to run? Is it in the current directory? If it isn't in the current directory you will need to specify the full file path to the jar.

Answer (score 0):

I tried using the pathname to run the jar from the terminal which gave me a string of errors. I then redownloaded JDK 21 which worked. Thank you greg-449 for the help which lead me to the answer.